# how to append and remove div based on textbox value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, loops, append

Here is my code i want to append data based on all three textbox if textbox value is 2 and textbox2's value is 3 and textbox3's value is 1 the The result will be 2 apple  3banans and 1 cherry and user can also remove items with textbox value
I have tried to make this code but it is removing all items could you please help me to solve this problem

```js
$(".change_qty").change(function(){
    var total = $(this).val();
    var oldLength = $(".box > span").length;
    var change = total - oldLength;
  var data_text= $(this).data("text");

    if (change > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < change; i++) {
            $(".box").append(`<span >${data_text}<br /></span>`);
        }
    }
    else {
        change = Math.abs(change)
        $( ".box > span" ).each(function( index ) {             
            $(this).remove();
            if (index == (change -1)) {
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input class="form-control input-sm change_qty"  type="number" data-text="apple">
<input class="form-control input-sm change_qty"  type="number" data-text="bananas">
<input class="form-control input-sm change_qty"  type="number" data-text="cherry">

 <div class="box" ></div>
```

Comment: @Lain what changes should I do to achieve desired result?

Comment: but what if there are more than 3 boxes it will difficult to manage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(".box > span").length` does not regard your different input types. It might be easier to clear everything and recreate the whole output on change. That way the entries also keep the order of `input`.

```js
$(".change_qty").change(function(){
  //REM: Remove all entries
  $(".box").empty();

  //REM: Recreate all entries
  $(".change_qty").each(function(){
    let tThis = $(this);
    let tText = tThis.data('text');
    let tQuantity = Math.abs(tThis.val());
    
    //REM: Append quantity of entries to .box
    for(let i=0, j=tQuantity; i<j; i++){
      $(".box").append(`<span >${tText}<br /></span>`)
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control input-sm change_qty"  type="number" data-text="apple">
<input class="form-control input-sm change_qty"  type="number" data-text="bananas">
<input class="form-control input-sm change_qty"  type="number" data-text="cherry">

<div class="box" ></div>
```

Comment: I have just chnaged this  $(".six_Products").find(`.single_product[data-id='${data_id}']`).length; and it workes perfect thanks